# Build time taking more time and memory (.NET Core Host and Visual Studio Code) using .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am using .NET Core 3.1.2 in the Visual Studio Code editor.

After I execute `dotnet publish` or `dotnet build`.

It is taking more time to build the application.

Sometimes the build completed within one minute. Most of the time it took ages to complete the build process.

The below is the architecture I am using:

#### File *Project.WebAPI*

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Persistence\Project.Persistence.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Application\Project.Application.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

#### File *Project.Application*

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Domain\Project.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Persistence\Project.Persistence.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Infrastructure\Project.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

#### File *Project.Domain*

> No other library referred to this.

#### File *Project.Persistence*

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Domain\Project.Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have checked where the build time takes more.

In the *Project.Domain* library the build is taking more time (almost 10 minutes)

In [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), *.NET Core Host* occupied more memory.

Comment: Re *Task Scheduler*: Do you mean *[Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows))*?

Answer (score 0):

The persistence project has all the migration files.

I have noticed that folder has more than 90 migration files.

After I removed all the files by using below steps,

```
Step 1: Delete all the migration scripts in the Migrations folder.

Step 2: In the package manager console: run

        PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate

Step 3: Delete the code for both the Up() and Down() methods. Before you do this, keep those methods saved elsewhere as we will need them again in step 5.

Step 4: Run:

        PM> Update-Database

It'll insert a new record into __EFMigrationsHistory table.

Step 5: After that, fill the above migration scripts (i.e., ..._InitialCreate) Up() and Down() method from the content kept in a safe place from Step 3.
```

The build problem is resolved.